# Increase spacing between consecutive datalist items

Tags: html, css, html-datalist

I am using a datalist to display a drop down as

```
<datalist id="ddl1">
    <option value="one">Apple</option>
    <option vlaue="two">Mango</option>
    <option value="three">Cherry</option>
</datalist>
```

How can I increase the spacing between 2 datalist rows. If I try adding

```
<option value="one">One<br /></option>
```

This shows up fine in Safari but shows a `<br />` as text in chrome.

How can this be resolved.

Comment: You've included the css tag. Use css.

Comment: You mean when this shows up under the input?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible as of yet. Recent versions of Chrome don't show the `<br />` as text anymore, but also don't render a newline in the dropdown.

Generally this should be fixed with CSS as it's a styling problem, but that doesn't work either. The actual `datalist` element only provides values for the suggestion dropdown, but the element itself is not shown. The list you see resides in the shadow DOM, just like (for example) the up/down arrows on an `<input type="number" />`.

One would hope for some `datalist` pseudo-selectors like `input::-webkit-outer-spin-button` that Chrome has for the number controls, but none have been specced or implemented for `datalist` at all.